# CSS - dropdown effect not working for IE-8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am not able to get this code working properly on IE-8. I am sorry as I am beginner in CSS.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:py="http://purl.org/kid        /ns#">
   <head>
       <meta name="generator" content= "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
       <meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
       <link href="/site_media/css-dock-menu/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/new.css"/>
   </head>
   </body>
       <ul class="navbar">
         <li style="width:9%;">
            <a href="#">Useful Sites</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="default1.aspx">Portal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="default2.aspx">Calender</a></li>
              </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
          [....]
```

Basically Hovering over "Useful Sites" should display drop down having "Portal" and "Calender".

Here is my new.css -

```
#wrap   {
        width: 100%; 
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0; 
        z-index: 99; 
        position: relative;
        background-color: #366b82;
        }

.navbar {
        height: 20px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        left-margin: 0;
        position: absolute; 
        right: 0;

        }

.navbar li {
                        height: auto;
                        width: 125px;  
                        float: left;  
                        list-style: none;  
            }

.navbar a       {
                padding: 10px 0;  
                border-left: 1px solid #54879d;
                border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
                text-decoration: none; 
                color: white; 
                display: block;
                }

.navbar li ul   {
                display: none; 
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; 
                }

.navbar li:hover ul     {
                        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
                        }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: (1) Which version(s) of IE????  (2) Have you got a valid doctype at the top of your page? (if not, that's your problem right there)  (3) What rendering mode is IE using?

Comment: @Spudley I am sorry, do I need to put doctype in it ? Its works fine without it on chrome and firefox. I tried on IE-8 but I dont undetstand the rendering part :( How do I find out ?

Comment: Yes, you do need to put in a doctype. Without one, you will end up in Quirks Mode. Quirks mode is basically an IE5-compatibility mode, which means that a whole stack of stuff will break.

Comment: Re Rendering mode: As I said, without a doctype the rendering mode will be "Quirks mode". But IE also has other compatibility modes which are also best avoided. You can find out what mode the browser is in by pressing F12 to get the dev tools window. The best way to ensure cross-browser compatibility is to keep IE in Standards Mode. That basically means having a valid doctype and setting `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=edge` You can find out more about these two things elsewhere here on SO, or you may want to [read my blog post on the subject](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode).

Comment: Thanks. Good post. I added doctype and @Gotschi suggestion and it worked ! I love SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need as below

```
.navbar li a:hover ul 
 {
  display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your problem right now as I have no access to IE lower than 9 (macbook running bootcamp) :/

Comment: Can I put some alert box inside CSS to see which function is called or not ?

Comment: You are my Hero ! Added < Doctype > and your suggestion worked. Thanks Brother.